# Change background-image from array using setInterval, but only twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, jinja2, setinterval

## Objective

I'm trying to change the `background-image: url` of a `<div>` every four seconds based off images from an array using `setInterval`

- There can be up to four images in the array
- Where I'm getting stuck is that I need to loop over the array twice and then return to the first image in the array before stopping `setInterval.`

## Where I'm at

Right now, the background-image only switches once before stopping. I should mention that I'm using Jinja with some JavaScript, but the two languages syntactically contain similarities.

### scripts.js

```
    $(function() {

        // Array of images
        var carouselImages = [

            // Returns a list containing a progression of integers
            // Similar to iterating over an array
            {% for n in range(1, coursePhotos) %}
                "{{ COPY.content.cdn_url }}/courses/{{course.slug}}/{{course.slug}}-{{n}}.jpg",
            {% endfor %}
        ];

        // The div of the background I want to change
        var carousel = $(".course__images");

        // Change the background image every four seconds
        var changeBackgroundImage = setInterval(function(){

            // Returns a list containing a progression of integers
            // Similar to iterating over an array
            {% for n in range(1, coursePhotos) %}
                carousel.css("background-image", "url({{ COPY.content.cdn_url }}/courses/{{course.slug}}/{{course.slug}}-{{n}}.jpg");
            {% endfor %}
        }, 4000);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example

```
var images = [
  'https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=one&w=100&h=100',
  'https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=two&w=100&h=100',
  'https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=three&w=100&h=100',
  'https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=four&w=100&h=100'
];

var img = document.querySelector('#image');
var index = 0;
var iterations = 0;

var updateImage = function() {
  /* reset index to zero if current index is greater than number of images.
   * increment iterations variable since it means we've done one whole loop.
   */
  if (index >= images.length) {
    index = 0;
    iterations++;
  }

  // set the background image
  img.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[index] + ')';

  /* clear interval (stop timer) when we've reached
   * the number of iterations allowed.
   */
  if (iterations >= 2) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  } else {
    /* increment current index in order to get next image
     * when this function gets called again.
     */
    index++;
  }
}

// update first image
updateImage();

// initiate timer
var interval = setInterval(updateImage, 4000);
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3wayry32/1/**

Comment: Looks solid. I was hoping you could describe in more detail what's happening inside `updateImage`.

Comment: added some comments @AndrewNguyen